# Flying with a desktop computer (as checked luggage)

Tags: air-travel, airlines, luggage, united-airlines

On an upcoming trip, I will be taking a desktop computer and monitor as checked luggage (on a United/Continental flight). What should I be aware of when doing this? What needs to be done to properly protect all the components? Are there any airline policies I should be aware of?

Comment: Also see: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/shipping-a-computer-from-europe-to-the-u-s

Comment: Buy a soft-shell suitcase and covered your PC with clothes is already ok. Same effect, lower cost, more remained weight(hard-shell suitcase are bulky)

Comment: Obviously the safest solution is to not check it -- instead bring it as a carry-on. I've done this. If the computer is within the weight and dimension limits of your carrier for carryon luggage, then there is apparently no reason why you can't bring it with you onboard.

Comment: I think I would fill it with packing peanuts and then wrap it in fleece filts, then of course take out the hard drive. I would then pack it into a hard bag and I'll make sure that the desktop has no space to slide around.

Comment: So at the end how was your experience i wanna travel with united and bring my desktop and monitor with me i think i will put the monitor on Checked baggage and bring the computer on a carry-on because it's an small one or maybe i disarm it if cant fit on the carry-on and still bring it on carry-on disarm

Comment: I think the best way is just disassemble your PC parts like Motherboard, HDD, Power Supply etc and leave the casing. You can buy new casing and reassemble to that new casing from your new destination country. This is most safest easiest way. Because you no need to worry about parts being not broken or anything during travel.

Comment: I do not know what you guys are talking about. You can carry a laptop or desktop in the checked baggage without any problem. I have been doing this for past several years.

Comment: This question was asked about 10 years ago, computers have changed in that time.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A friend recently did this, flying from LON (London) to SYD (Sydney).

I went shopping with him and found a hard-shell suitcase.  They're surprisingly light, and [Samsonite has claimed theirs is "strong enough to stand on"](https://www.samsonite.co.uk/history/#history-year_1910).

[image]

We then removed his harddisk drive.  This is the most valuable and most fragile part of the computer.  It's also feasible to do the same with the sticks of RAM and other parts, but the harddrive is the critical bit.

This was packed in an anti-static bag, and bubble wrapped, and I believe he actually took it on his carry-on to make sure he had it safe at all times.

Aside from that, you check the suitcase in just as per normal.  I'd perhaps put some jerseys or other clothes in the suitcase with the computer to try and give it just that extra bit of protection, and to prevent it from sliding around too much if it's not an exact fit.

Comment: I've done almost exactly what Mark Mayo has posted here.  I didn't even use a hard-case suitcase and I simply packed clothes around the whole desktop and monitor.  Customs may ask to inspect your hardware in your carry-on but that's the only issue I had.

Comment: I read the part that says "put some jerseys or other clothes in the case" and nearly died... Then realized you meant *suit*case! Oops lol

Comment: I would suggest removing the CPU cooler if it is a large model. These can put quite a large torque/cantilever on the motherboard even when sitting still, so can do some damaged if bumped etc.

Comment: One thing that has changed in the almost 9 years since the original answer is that many computers don't have a classic "spinning" hard drive (if yours does, then the precaution described here would still be valid) but a SSD drive, in which case there is no need to remove it as, unlike a HDD, it's just as impact resistant or fragile as the rest of the electronics inside.

Comment: @Peteris fair, although the concern was also for the data.  The rest of the computer is 'replaceable' with insurance, but your data is critical.  Saying that, what's also changed is internet speeds. I personally have everything backed up to the cloud just in case (too many bad experiences)

Comment: Some newer gaming cases have glass in front or on the side to show off the lighted fans inside.  If you know you are traveling with it, maybe don't get that case.  I did just help pack one - we used a 29" hard shell suitcase, and the Styrofoam blocks from its original box fit into the suitcase, keeping all sides (including the glass ones) a safe distance from all sides of the suitcase.  The graphics card was removed to avoid damage from the g-forces of the bumps and possible drops.  It was checked and arrived unscathed.

Answer (score 11):

I must take George's comment to an answer because it's too important: depending on the kind, the heatsink may need to be removed. Apply common sense / guess the centre of gravity. If it looks like this:

[image]

it very likely will cause no problems. If it looks like this:

[image]

you definitely do not want that bumping around.

Comment: Before removing a heat sink,  remember that you'll need to reapply the thermal paste.  Unless you know exactly how to do that,  keep the heat sink in place.

Comment: Most of the time only enthusiasts who assemble computers themselves will have large tower coolers.

Answer (score 7):

I personally would take some precautions. First of all, make a backup of your data. Leave on in your home and take another one with you so that you can use it in your destination place. Then when transporting a desktop computer, the most fragile part is almost always the hard disk drive. So I would dismount it if possible and take it into your cabin luggage. You could also do this for other sensible parts like for example other drives, the processor, or the RAM bars. This I would pack into anti-static bags and take it into the cabin.

The tower itself you can put into protected pc transporting bags like [this one](http://www.frozencpu.com/cat/l1/g31/Travel_Cases.html). This bag will be checked so that you can't smuggle and weapons or drugs. But you shouldn't normally fear that this will damage your computer.

And last but not least, you could also think about sending your computer with a carrier. I quote this from a message board:

> Send it via a Secured Carrier, RPS(Royal Packaging Service), Which
>   Delivers Things in the most pristine state Possible. Door to door
>   Service, White glove care. But i warn you, Its pricey. 15lb =
>   $200/USD.

Answer (score 2):

I've shipped the kid's gaming computer twice on an airline.  Both times it was partially disassembled on arrival.  With a huge heatsink for the chip, it must look suspicious to the uninformed at TSA.  Had to rebuild it both times.  Third time, FedEX - same thing.

Comment: For the future it would be worth looking at the recommendations for the 'huge heatsink' - there's often a warning that they should be removed before shipping due to the stresses that they can put on the motherboard.

Comment: I carefully padded and packed a laptop into the center (clothes on all sides) of a checked bag.  At the other end, all the wrappings had been removed, and nothing was between the laptop and corner of the bag.  Due to this and other things I've witnessed, my laptop is now ALWAYS carried on.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of the case and your level of pain tolerance, it may also be possible to take it as carry-on luggage.

I've done that twice now, although with a small flat desktop PC (that is within hand luggage size regulations), and aside from being taken aside at security for explosives screening (which involved me opening the case) and actually carrying the thing around, it was easy enough.