# Traveling with computer parts and expensive monitor to Dublin

Tags: luggage, electronic-items, belgium, ryanair, dublin

I have to move computer components, a 850 euro monitor screen and a cheaper one to Dublin. I think to put them in my luggage, but I'm a bit afraid it will get stolen. The trip is from Belgium, I can choose from a few airlines (Aer lingus, Ryanair) and airports (Brussels airport or Charleroi South Airport).

I have a [normal luggage](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-moxOPBxwKzw/T7VWcSt_AoI/AAAAAAAAApM/tqo6Vpiy9Lc/s1600/Lime+Suitcase%5B1%5D.jpg), without any special locks. Only a 4 number lock.
I still have the original box of the screen, so throwing with the luggage shouldn't be a problem.

Is this a good idea? Should I rather send it with DHL, Fedex, ...?

(*secondary question*)
What would be the best airline and airport to travel with these electronics?

Comment: I added it as a secondary question.

Comment: what do you mean by best? the best airline to transfer the monitors for you safely?

Comment: yes, safely and not stolen.

Comment: Do you have to fly? Eurostar to London then a (cheap!) Rail+Sail ticket onward to Dublin would let you keep them with you at all times. Might not be very much more money than a flight with baggage allowance, though it would be slower

Comment: @Gagravarr thats a good idea, I didn't even think about that!

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3984/16567

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer

If you're not in a huge rush, I'd suggest you skip flying, and take the train. Well, train + train + ferry. That way, you'll have the computer parts and monitor with you at all times, can keep an eye on them, can ensure that no baggage handlers throw them about it.

Booked a little bit in advance, it's actually not that expensive either, especially when you factor in that there's no checked / oversized luggage to pay for!

First up, you'll want to take the Eurostar to London. Journey time is around 2 hours, and tickets cost *from* about €50 (they go up nearer departure). If you're not starting your journey in Brussels, you'll want to book an *Any Belgian Station* ticket. That adds about €10 to a one-way ticket, but will give you a ticket from anywhere in Belgium on the train to Brussels to connect with your Eurostar. More details on the [Seat61 Belgium page](http://seat61.com/Belgium.htm)

Eurostar officially [allow 2 large items plus one small one](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-information/travel-planning/luggage/luggage-allowances), of any weight that you yourself can carry. Unofficially, you can often manage a little more than that, but they may be stricter on the rules if the train is very busy.

The Eurostar will drop you at St Pancras station. You need to get to Euston station, which is quite close. See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25522/whats-the-quickest-way-from-london-kings-cross-to-euston-by-foot-or-tube) on the quickest way between the two. (St Pancras is right next to Kings Cross, on the Euston side)

From Euston, there are direct trains to Holyhead, and you can buy combined train+ferry tickets. These cost a whopping £38 one way! See the [Seat61 Ireland page for details](http://seat61.com/Ireland.htm#recommended%20option). It takes about 4 hours to Holyhead, then another 2-3 to Ireland, depending on if you get the fast or the slow ferry. There's some very picturesque scenery on the way.

On arrival in Dublin, you can take a bus from the ferry terminal, or probably you'd want a taxi given how much stuff you'll have

Not quick, but with the Eurostar booked in advance you can do it for under £100!

Comment: I traveled to Dublin this way. Note that you still need to check in your luggage at the ferry. On departure you can hear them trowing the bags. On arrival you see them getting the bags out of a truck. Next time I will be taking the plane the 11 + hours journey isn't worth it. the screens and computer are undamaged but I think one of my old hard drives is broken.

Comment: I thought that checking bags was optional not compulsory? Sorry to hear something died on the way :(

Comment: Maybe it depends on the type of ferry. I wouldn't want to carry 2 bags of each +40kg 3 levels up. The most expensive parts are not damaged, that's most important! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Freddy If you want to bring 2 bags of +40 kg onto a flight, you'll have to pay a pretty penny for that (max. weight limit is generally 32kg, so you'll have to check in your luggage as cargo-freight).

Comment: the train allows you any bags you can carry. I did this the second time from Dublin to Belgium (taxi - ferry - train - train - eurostar - train - taxi) with two bags total weight of about 95 kg took 16 hours. I was out for about a weak because of my back. Really not worth it.

Answer (score 11):

I have flown from the USA to Thailand with computer monitors in my checked baggage without issue on a couple of recent occasions (and I use a roller duffel, so effectively zero protection against theft).

Most thievery from luggage is small, easy to conceal items like jewelry, cameras, phones, tablets, music players.  A big monitor in its original box is too big to be casually concealed and carried past security at the end of the work day.

While the factory box is usually pretty good protection, I have always stuck some folded up clothing in the empty space between the screen and box, just for a bit more protection against crushing or penetration of the cardboard.

Your choice of airline or airport would have little bearing on this, as it would simply depend on which ramp rats were handling your baggage that day.  Most airlines/airports have hard working and also lazy employees and it is just the luck of the draw whom gets to handle your baggage.