# Checked baggage bubble wrapped only

Tags: air-travel, luggage

I would like to take a non-collapsible, ornamental metal music stand on an airplane as a checked item. Will it be accepted if it is only wrapped in bubble wrap with shrink wrap exterior + cord for securing on handling.

Comment: Which airline? Have you checked their baggage guidance online?

Comment: Also, have you checked it fits the max weight and dimensions (usually the sum of length + width + height should be < 150 or 158 cm)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I simply bubble wrap a cardboard box and check it on a US domestic flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38953/can-i-simply-bubble-wrap-a-cardboard-box-and-check-it-on-a-us-domestic-flight)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but keep in mind that checked baggage travels a considerable distance on automated machinery. The bubble wrap is more likely to snag or tear, especially with an odd sized item such as a music stand. It would be worth your time to break down a card board box and make a makeshift enclosure to go around the bubble wrap for extra protection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check in anything which fits in the airline specific weight and dimensions as long as the check-in staff is sure that you don't transport any prohibited items and that the package is not  to fragile. They might not accept it, when they believe it won't survive the flight.