# Can I put my desktop pc into checked in luggage?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel

My PC case is heavy, so I will only bring the following:
-Motherboard
-RAM sticks
-Video Card
-3 HDDs (Planning to put this on handcarry)
-Power Supply
-AIO Cooler (water cooler)
-Keyboard and Mouse (can go to hand carry too)

New Monitor and case will be bought from destination.

They will all be disassembled and put into boxes (Thinking it could fit into the original Motherboard and PSU boxes).

I'm going to US and I really don't mind it being checked by TSA as long as it won't get broken. :)

Comment: Is your question whether the airline will accept it? Look [at this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/can-i-pack-a-cardboard-box-as-checked-luggage) to see if it answers some of your concerns.

Comment: I do think they will. It's a major airline in the US. :) Plus my luggage is TSA friendly so they can open it all they want.

Comment: But what is your question, then? You don't go through a TSA check on arrival; it would be Customs and Immigration.