# Can I bring desktop PC components from India to USA?

Tags: usa, luggage, legal, india

I want to bring desktop components from India to USA including a processor, graphics card, motherboard, ram, ssd, and a monitor. I will be carrying it in a handheld carrying case as a check-in luggage. Will I face any problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bring my desktop computer as check-in baggage on a flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16266/can-i-bring-my-desktop-computer-as-check-in-baggage-on-a-flight)

Answer (score 2):

You can take it on flight but there are some issues.

The main thing is damage.  There may be a chance of the item to get damaged.

Also you should consider packing it in Electro-static discharge bag.

Otherwise, no issues.

Anyway you should consider the carry on regulations.

Just for a reference : http://www.latimes.com/travel/la-trb-carry-on-luggage-size-20140611-story.html

Comment: yes i would be carrying them in electro sattic bag within this type of case. http://ak1.ostkcdn.com/img/mxc/090901_hard_luggage.jpg

Comment: Also check the size of luggage each carrier allows