# Can I bring personal computer from UK to Ukraine for personal use?

Tags: transportation, ukraine

I will be travelling to Ukraine for a 1-2 months and I am wondering if I could bring my personal computer with me (for personal use of course), or is this prohibited?

Comment: There is already a similar question posted here -> https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16266/39061 Basically the answer is yes but with some precautions to consider -> https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/16267/39061

Answer (score 2):

As others say: yes, you can.

I would however recommend shipping it to the destination instead of taking it with you. It will mostly prevent damaging your computer.

Comment: Having seen how parcel services handle the parcels, I doubt it is better than hold luggage.

Comment: @Willeke It's more or less the same, I send and receive various electronics, including computers without issues at all or damaged packages so I would consider it safer. Depends on multiple factors

Comment: It will depend a lot on how the things are packaged. Professional packaging is often better than what people at home do.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, You can!

I often travel from UK to Ukraine and have no problems bringing one or even two laptops for personal use with me. The same will be if i take my PC :).