# Moving to Netherlands from Kazakhstan with my PC

Tags: luggage, electronic-items, western-europe, lot-polish-airlines

I will be flying to Amsterdam from Nur-Sultan with a connecting leg in Warsaw. The airline is LOT Polish airlines on both legs. I was thinking to bring my PC with me to Amsterdam. My plan is to carry the following components:

- Motherboard with CPU and RAM sticks on it (I will remove the battery and get it into carry on luggage)
- Grahpics card (RTX 3080 from Palit)
- Power supply (800W)
- CPU Cooler
- A stack of SSDs and HDDs

For everything but SSDs and HDDs I have their original packaging, including manuals and even the original purchase document I have for them. I would like to submit all of my PC components into checked in luggage. Will that cause any problems? PSU in particular looks like a bomb to those not familiar with PC components. I could ship it from Kazakhstan, but that will cost me about one third of the price of the PC, without any insurance.

How bad is my idea? Should I try something else? Can I at least bring motherboard and my graphics card?

---

I have tried contacting LOT airlines but I could not reach a living person to ask questions regarding my PC components.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flying with a desktop computer (as checked luggage)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/flying-with-a-desktop-computer-as-checked-luggage)

Comment: @lambshaanxy unfortunately I haven’t seen anything specific like a rule specifically allowing computer components to be checked in. I have read in LOT’s help center that computers are prohibited in check in luggage.