# Bringing a PC tower with water cooling as checked luggage on an airplane

Tags: air-travel, luggage, electronic-items

I am planning to take my PC Tower as a checked luggage on an airplane. I have already looked for answers online and I know that it is allowed by the TSA.

I have also spoken to my PC Build company, who gave me instructions on how to pack it. They told me to confirm with Corsair that their cooler will be able to hold up in the pressurized section of the plane, where checked luggage is stored. Some coolers can leak or even "explode" according to the PC Build company. I have contacted Corsair, but I have not received an answer yet and their phone support will not be available until February, which is before my flight.

Has anyone ever put a PC Tower with a "Corsair H100i PRO - 240mm Liquid CPU Cooler" in checked luggage? Is it safe? I will be removing the GPU, HDD and SSD drives and taking them in my carry-on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flying with a desktop computer (as checked luggage)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/flying-with-a-desktop-computer-as-checked-luggage)

Comment: Don’t forget to perform a full backup before leaving.

Comment: The case itself is the bulkiest part of the PC, very fragile and also quite cheap. I'd consider packaging each component individually like you said, but I'd just leave the case at home and buy a new one at your destination.

Comment: have you considered draining and refilling the cooling liquid for the duration of the flight?

Comment: I have edited the subject to make it clear water cooling is involved, as that _possibly_ makes it different from other similar questions. Correct me if I got it wrong (maybe it’s not even water).

Comment: @PeterM This is a sealed unit, and cannot be drained

Answer (score 5):

The cargo hold of passenger aircraft is pressurized to the same level as of cabin. The atmospheric pressure at sea level is 14.7 PSI. The minimum allowed pressure is 10.9 PSI ([8000ft equivalent](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-altitude-pressure-d_462.html)), which is about 3.8 PSI difference. It is comfortable enough to breathe for you. It should not cause the well sealed liquid cooler to leak/burst. Unless a rapid depressurization happens, which is very rare.

Being said that, your biggest challenge is how the cargo is handled. Even with fragile stickers, the probability that your packed bag thrown and all is really high. Damaged caused by that is much more destructive to the cabin and liquid cooler. So, if you really want no damage, pack it well so that it won't get damaged while being thrown around.

*Note: Those coolers are regularly transported using airplanes by manufactures and distributors.*

Comment: If there's a rapid depressurization, the fate of the computer and water cooling system will likely be very low on the priority list.